# Proving that the square of a particular Brownian Motion approaches zero as its Quadratic Variation approaches 0?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

I'm working on this problem for my stochastic analysis course:

> For $t \geq 0,$ let $W_t$ be a Wiener process defined on $( \Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb{P})$, and let $$Q_{\Pi} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^3.$$
>   Also, let $|| \Pi || = \text{max}_{0 \leq i \leq n-1}(t_{i+1}-t_i).$
>
> Prove that as $|| \Pi || \rightarrow 0$, $\text{ } \mathbb{E}(Q_\Pi^2) \rightarrow 0.$

To be honest, I am not confident in my proof. Here is what I have so far; my strategy is to factor out a $(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^2$ and bound it by $||\Pi||$:

$$\mathbb{E}\big(Q_{\Pi}^2\big) = \mathbb{E}\bigg( \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^3(W_{t_{j+1}}-W_{t_{j}})^3 \bigg)$$

$$\leq \mathbb{E}\big((W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})^2\big) \mathbb{E}\bigg( \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})(W_{t_{j+1}}-W_{t_{j}})^3 \bigg)$$

$$= (t_{i+1}-t_{i}) \cdot \mathbb{E}\bigg( \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})(W_{t_{j+1}}-W_{t_{j}})^3 \bigg)$$

$$\leq ||\Pi|| \cdot \mathbb{E}\bigg( \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_{i}})(W_{t_{j+1}}-W_{t_{j}})^3 \bigg),$$

which should approach zero as $||\Pi|| \rightarrow 0$.

How could I prove the implied statement in the problem? i.e., what am I missing? Is there a better way to approach this?

**EDIT**

Per Youem's suggestion in the comments, I've decided to Expectational value where i=j. This is what I get:
$$(Q^2_Π)=\sum_{i=0}^{n−1}((W_{t_{i+1}}−W_{t_i})^6)$$

Not entirely sure where to go from here.

Comment: Try to compute the expected value exactly. It should not be difficult since you have to consider only the case of $i=j$ in the sum

Comment: Thanks @Youem, see my addition above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu = \mathbb E [Z^6]$ for $Z\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$. Since $W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i} \sim \mathcal N(0, t_{i+1} -t_i)\sim (t_{i+1} - t_i)^\frac12\mathcal N (0,1)$, $$\mathbb E \left[ \left( W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i}\right)^6 \right] = \mu (t_{i+1}- t_i)^3 \le \mu \left\|\mathbb \Pi\right\|^2 (t_{i+1}-t_i)$$ then $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} E \left[ \left( W_{t_{i+1}} - W_{t_i}\right)^6 \right] \le \mu \left\|\mathbb \Pi\right\|^2 (t_{i+1}-t_i) = \mu \left\|\mathbb \Pi\right\|^2 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(t_{i+1} -t_i\right) = \mu\left\|\mathbb \Pi\right\|^2 (t_n - t_0)$$ then $$\mathbb E[Q_\Pi^2] \le \mu \Pi^2 (t_n -t_0) \le \mu \left\|\Pi\right\|^2 t$$

Comment: Thanks, but how did you get $\mathcal N(0, t_{i+1} -t_i)\sim (t_{i+1} - t_i)^\frac32\mathcal N (0,1)$? It could be correct, but I don't see it anywhere in my course's notes/text. Perhaps there's a way around that? Any further clarification, or any way to get the result without a new Brownian motion $Z$?

Comment: It is not correct. I edit my answer the correct answer is $\mathcal N (0,\sigma^2) \sim \sigma \mathcal N (0,1)$

Comment: It is easy to prove. Indeed, if $Z \sim \mathcal N (0,1)$ then for every $\sigma \in \mathbb R$, $\sigma Z \sim \mathcal N (0, \sigma^2)$ ($\mathbb E [\sigma Z] = \sigma \mathbb E[Z] = 0$, and $\text{Var}[\sigma Z] = \sigma^2 \text{Var} [Z] = \sigma^2$)

Comment: Youem, thank you- your comments are clarifying it a little bit, but one final question- I'm not sure what steps you took after you said "after summation." Care to elaborate on that?

Comment: Is it clear now ?

Comment: Absolutely- thanks!